# Pushpool GUI Miner failed to subscribe

Tags: mining-pools

I'm trying to setup a pool for me and my friends as a test to start with put i have it all setup but it's not working properly,

GUI Miner Console output

```
2013-03-30 19:08:43: Running command: poclbm.exe barkermn01.01:r5kjp9lk@192.168.0.9:8342 --device=1 --platform=0 --verbose -r1 
2013-03-30 19:08:43: Listener for "Second Miner" started
2013-03-30 19:08:46: Listener for "Second Miner": 192.168.0.9:8342 30/03/2013 19:08:46, started OpenCL miner on platform 0, device 1 (AMD A8-3870 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics)
2013-03-30 19:08:46: Listener for "Second Miner": 192.168.0.9:8342 30/03/2013 19:08:46, checking for stratum...
2013-03-30 19:08:46: Listener for "Second Miner": 192.168.0.9:8342 30/03/2013 19:08:46, no response to getwork, using as stratum
2013-03-30 19:08:56: Listener for "Second Miner": 192.168.0.9:8342 30/03/2013 19:08:56, Failed to subscribe
2013-03-30 19:08:58: Listener for "Second Miner": 192.168.0.9:8342 30/03/2013 19:08:58, IO errors - 1, tolerance 2
2013-03-30 19:09:08: Listener for "Se2013-03-30 19:09:10: Listener for "Second Miner": 192.168.0.9:8342 30/03/2013 19:09:10, IO errors - 2, tolerance 2
2013-03-30 19:09:11: Listener for "Second Miner" shutting down
```

Server Response

```
[2013-03-30 19:08:38.356196] Listening on host :: port 8342
[2013-03-30 19:08:38.360453] Listening on host :: port 8341
[2013-03-30 19:08:38.361248] Listening on host :: port 8332
[2013-03-30 19:08:38.363738] Listening on host 127.0.0.1 port 8338
[2013-03-30 19:08:38.371768] initialized
[2013-03-30 19:08:46.337346] client host ::ffff:192.168.0.7 port 62008 connected
[2013-03-30 19:08:46.339029] client host ::ffff:192.168.0.7 port 62009 connected
[2013-03-30 19:08:58.343650] client host ::ffff:192.168.0.7 port 62010 connected
[2013-03-30 19:09:10.348276] client host ::ffff:192.168.0.7 port 62011 connected
```

does any one know what this error means and how i stop it?